How to perform accurate FixedPoint Number Calculation in C?
How to perform accurate FixedPoint Number Calculation in C ??
I use the struct in C to store the integer part and the fraction part.
I guess the function is incorrect, maybe didn't handle the overflow properly, but  I don't know how to modify it.
The input is like:
3.14123412345 + 0.23
5.6324 - 6.43252
8.112 * 1.31

My outputs is:
3.000000
-1.000000
0.000000

The outputs of my program are completely wrong, the precision of the numbers is lost when stored or calculated.
Here is my code:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#define maxn 110000
#define uint unsigned int
#define ull unsigned long long
typedef struct {
    int intgr;
    uint frac;
}PointFixedNum;
PointFixedNum a,b,ans;
char s1[maxn],s2[maxn],op;
double num1=0.0,num2=0.0;
void init(PointFixedNum *a,double num)
{
    a->intgr=(int)num;
    a->frac=(uint)((ull)(num-a->intgr)<<32);
}
void clear()
{
    a.frac=b.frac=ans.frac=0;
    a.frac=b.frac=ans.frac=0;
    num1=0.0;
    num2=0.0;
}
void read()
{
    scanf("%1100[^ ]",s1);
    scanf(" %c",&op);
    scanf("%1100s",s2);
    sscanf(s1,"%lf",&num1);
    sscanf(s2,"%lf",&num2);
}
PointFixedNum add(PointFixedNum a,PointFixedNum b)
{
    PointFixedNum c;
    ull sum=(ull)a.frac+b.frac;
    c.frac=(uint)(sum&((1ULL<<32)-1));
    c.intgr=a.intgr+b.intgr+(int)(sum>>32);
    return c;
}
PointFixedNum sub(PointFixedNum a,PointFixedNum b)
{
    PointFixedNum c;
    ull diff=(ull)a.frac-b.frac;
    c.frac=(uint)(diff&((1ULL<<32)-1));
    c.intgr=a.intgr-b.intgr-(int)(diff>>32);
}
PointFixedNum mul(PointFixedNum a,PointFixedNum b)
{
    PointFixedNum c;
    ull pro1=(ull)a.intgr*b.intgr;
    ull pro2=(ull)a.frac*b.frac;
    ull temp=(ull)((ull)pro1<<32)+(ull)pro2;
    c.intgr=(int)(temp>>32);
    c.frac=(uint)(temp&((1ULL<<32)-1));
}
void print(PointFixedNum a)
{
    double fraction=(double)a.frac/(1ULL<<32);
    double fin=(double)a.intgr+fraction;
    printf("%lf",fin);
}
int main()
{
    read();
    init(&a,num1);
    init(&b,num2);
    if(op=='+')
    {
        ans=add(a,b);
    }
    else if(op=='-')
    {
        ans=sub(a,b);
    }
    else if(op=='*')
    {
        ans=mul(a,b);
    }
    print(ans);
    return 0;
}

Updated:
I fixed some of the bugs in my program based on comments and answers, here is the result:
Inputs
3.14123412345 + 0.23
5.6324 - 6.43252
8.112 * 1.31

Outputs
3.37123412336
-0.80012000003
10.62671999843

So far, the functions of each function have been implemented, at least there should be no logical problem.
The only problem now is the precision, the add function will lost the precision after ten decimal places, as well as the sub function.
How to improve precision
Is there any way to improve the precision? Or the loss of precision is inevitable after ten decimal places?
If it is inevitable, since the process of the add and sub only relates to the shortest number, is there a way to keep the changeless part in the output?
for example: 3.14123412345 + 0.23 = 3.37123412345 , the first and second digit after decimal point (3.14) are added to 0.23 , but the 123412345 remained. Is there a way to keep it in the output directly?
About multiply
When the output result has a finite number of bits, the result is quite correct, so is there a way to limit the number of bits in the outputs to the same as the actual result?
for example: 8.112 * 1.31 = 10.62672 , if there is way to limit the output bits to 5, the output answer is correct.
This is my adjusted code:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#define maxn 110000
#define int int32_t
#define uint uint32_t
#define ull uint64_t
typedef struct {
    int intgr;
    uint frac;
}PointFixedNum;
PointFixedNum a,b,ans;
const ull scale=(1ULL<<32);
char s1[maxn],s2[maxn],op;
double num1=0.0,num2=0.0;
void init(PointFixedNum *a,double num)
{
    a->intgr=(int)num;
    a->frac=(uint)((num-a->intgr)*scale);
}
/*void init(PointFixedNum *a, double num) {
  static const long long scale = 1LL << 32;

  // Round to get y
  long long y = llround(num*scale);

  // Now break y into 2 parts:
  a->intgr = y/scale;
  int32_t frac = y%scale;
  if (frac >= 0) {
    a->frac = frac;
  } else {
    a->frac = scale + frac;
    a->intgr--;
  }
}*/
// I check this version and the result is the same.
void clear()
{
    a.frac=b.frac=ans.frac=0;
    a.frac=b.frac=ans.frac=0;
    num1=0.0;
    num2=0.0;
}
void read()
{
    scanf(" %1100[^ ]",s1);
    scanf(" %c",&op);
    scanf("%1100s",s2);
    sscanf(s1,"%lf",&num1);
    sscanf(s2,"%lf",&num2);
}
PointFixedNum add(PointFixedNum a,PointFixedNum b)
{
    PointFixedNum c;
    ull sum=(ull)a.frac+b.frac;
    c.frac=(uint)(sum%scale);
    c.intgr=a.intgr+b.intgr+(int)(sum/scale);
    return c;
}
PointFixedNum sub(PointFixedNum a,PointFixedNum b)
{
    PointFixedNum c;
    ull diff=(ull)a.frac-b.frac;
    c.frac=(uint)(diff%scale);
    c.intgr=a.intgr-b.intgr-(int)(diff/scale);
    return c;
}
PointFixedNum mul(PointFixedNum a,PointFixedNum b)
{
    PointFixedNum c={0,0};
    //ull scale=1ULL<<32;
    ull pro1=(ull)a.intgr*b.intgr;
    ull pro2=(ull)a.intgr*b.frac;
    ull pro3=(ull)a.frac*b.intgr;
    ull pro4=(ull)a.frac*b.frac;

    ull carry=pro4%scale>=scale/2;

    ull sum=pro4/scale+pro3%scale+pro2%scale+carry;
    c.frac=sum%scale;
    carry=sum/scale;

    sum=pro1%scale+pro2/scale+pro3/scale+carry;
    c.intgr=sum%scale;

    carry=sum/scale;
    sum=pro1/scale+carry;

    return c;
}
void print(PointFixedNum a)
{
    double fraction=(double)a.frac/scale;
    double fin=(double)a.intgr+fraction;
    printf("%.11lf",fin);
}
int main()
{
    read();
    init(&a,num1);
    init(&b,num2);
    if(op=='+')
    {
        ans=add(a,b);
    }
    else if(op=='-')
    {
        ans=sub(a,b);
    }
    else if(op=='*')
    {
        ans=mul(a,b);
    }
    print(ans);
    return 0;
}


What specific input produced what exact result and what did you expect instead? Hint: a minimal example almost never needs to parse stuff from input unless that's specifically what you're testing. You can set up two single hard-coded input values, add them, show the result, and say what it should have been instead.

Start small. Does reading a number from the input and printing it back work properly (hint1)? Once you get that working, don't forget to enable and read compiler warnings (hint2).

a->frac=(uint)((ull)(num-a->intgr)<<32); What do you expect to happen in your init function? Hint: Take a look at the C operator precedence table and check what happens first: Casting to ull or shifting left?

"maybe didn't handle the overflow properly" Which overflow do you mean? Does that mean, you verified that everything up the the first place where an overflow might happen, was tested OK? If not, what did you verify to be OK and how?

It is a bit awkward to use separate fields for the integer and fraction parts.  More typical would be to use a single int or long int or long long int for the whole value, and to interpret that according to an appropriate scale (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).  For example, maybe the least significant bit has place value 2^(-32).  If you use long long int then you will definitely have more bits than a typical double has bits of mantissa.  Depending on C implementation, long int might be enough to have that property.

@user27624792, 3.14123412345 + 0.23 = 3.37123412345 --> No.  All three of these values are not exactly representable by struct {  int intgr;  uint frac; }.  Instead there is a conversion error in taking 3.14123412345 and 0.23 into that struct.  It is those 2 converted values that are added and then that sum converted back to text (which incurs a small error due to rounding.   You need to adjust your expectations of what happens when converting to/from decimal text to PointFixedNum.

@user27624792, You keep changing the question as info arrives.  Perhaps it is time to address the original issue - was that solved?  If so perhaps post another question and this time be specified about input, output seen and output excited - a [mcve].

Code has at least these problems:
Incomplete multiplication
mul(PointFixedNum a,PointFixedNum b) is missing the a.intgr*b.frac and *b.intgr*a.frac part.
Insufficient printing
printf("%lf",fin); prints a 6 digits fraction part, yet the fixed fraction is 1 part in 232.  Code should print at least 10 digits to the right of the decimal point: printf("%.10lf",fin);
Not checking scanf() results

Always check the return value of scanf() to see if reading succeeded.

scanf("%1100[^ ]",s1); should be scanf(" %1100[^ ]",s1);  (add space) if read() is ever call again to consume any left over '\n' from prior input.
Too narrow an unsigned?
Instead of uint frac;, use uint32_t frac from <stdint.h> and avoid a dependency on unsigned size  (unsigned may be 16-bit especially on embedded platforms).
Addition error
@Adrian McCarthy and @Gerhardh caught add/subtract issue.

init() deeper dive
Aside from the significant error in (ull)(num-a->intgr)<<32, better to round to the nearest value (using a round function) than a cast to an integer, which truncates.
Sample untested code to illustrate the idea.
#include <math.h>

void init(PointFixedNum *a, double num) {
  static const long long scale = 1LL << 32;

  // Round to get y
  long long y = llround(num*scale);

  // Now break y into 2 parts:
  a->intgr = y/scale;
  int32_t frac = y%scale;
  if (frac >= 0) {
    a->frac = frac;
  } else {
    a->frac = scale + frac;
    a->intgr--;
  }
}


Multiply
To multiply 2 positive values follows.  OP will need to adjust things for mixed signed values.
Semi-pseudo-code
PointFixedNum mult(PointFixedNum a, PointFixedNum b) {
  ull scale = 1LL < 32;
  PointFixedNum c = 0;
  // Form the 4 64-bit products.
  ull pafbf = (ull)a.frac  * b.frac;  
  ull pafbi = (ull)a.frac  * b.ipart;
  ull paibf = (ull)a.ipart * b.frac;
  ull paibi = (ull)a.ipart * b.ipart;

  // These 4 products have a 32-bit most significant half
  // and a least 32-bit significant half.
  // Add these 8 32-bit values in columns of same significance.
  // Remember to carry. 
  //
  // paibi.upper paibi.lower
  //             paibf.upper paibf.lower
  //             pafbi.upper pafbi.lower
  //                         pafbf.upper pafbf.lower 
  // ===============================================
  // overflow        c.ipart     c.frac  

  // Round to form the first carry.
  ull carry = pafbf%scale >= scale/2;

  // Form the fraction.
  ull sum = pafbf/scale + pafbi%scale + paibf%scale + carry;
  c.frac = sum%scale;
  carry = sum / scale;

  // Form the integer part.
  sum = pafbi/scale + paibf/scale + paibi%scale + carry;
  c.ipart = sum%scale;
  carry = sum / scale;

  // Maybe form the overflow part.
  sum = paibi/scale + carry;
  // `sum` is the overflow part.
  // Perhaps do something special if it is non-zero as overflow occurred.

Advanced:
To round half-ways cases to nearest even, as done with common FP is trickier. Something like:
  // Form the fraction.
  ull sum = pafbf/scale + pafbi%scale + paibf%scale;
  if (sum & 1) {
    sum += pafbf%scale >= scale/2;
  } else {
    sum += pafbf%scale > scale/2;
  } 
  c.frac = sum%scale;
  carry = sum / scale;


Thanks! I've add my outputs.
But in addtion to my mul function, I think maybe my add and sub function have some problems.

Thanks!
I've adjusted my code, the add and sub are almost correct, and I want to know how to improve the precision.
Besides, I've adjusted the mul funcion but I don't know how to integrate the product.

@user27624792 To multiply is really the same as grade school multiplication of 2 two-digit numbers.  Rather than 2 base 10 digits, you have 2 base 2^32 "digits".

Thanks! The mul function works now, but I still have some questions about the precision and the outputs. I've edited  my post and writed them in it.

There's an error in the initialization function.
void init(PointFixedNum *a,double num)
{
    a->intgr=(int)num;

At this point a->intgr is the whole portion of num.  If num were 3.14123412345, then a->intgr would be 3.  So far so good.
Here's where things go wrong:
    a->frac=(uint)((ull)(num-a->intgr)<<32);

num - a->intgr results in a double containing the fractional portion of num (e.g., 0.14123412345).
That is then cast to an unsigned long long, which results in 0. Left-shifting 0 by 32 bits still results in 0, and casting back to unsigned int yields 0.  So a->frac is 0, and a now represents only the integer portion of num (e.g., 3.0).
My guess is that you intended to shift fraction up into the whole portion before truncating it to an integral type and got tripped up by the order of operations. (Casting has higher precedence than left-shift.)
One way to fix that is to multiply instead of shifting.
a->frac = (uint)((num - a->intgr) * (1ULL << 32));

With that change, your addition example works.  It also looks like it would explain the subtraction example you showed, but your sub() and mul() functions are both missing return statements, so you "got lucky" that it gave you any result at all.
